# STM32F4Discovery: Reading Serial Flash Manufacture/Device ID via SPI

Tags: stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I could use some help troubleshooting.  I'm trying to read the manufacturer and device ID from a W25Q128FV serial flash using SPI on an Arduino Due.

The flash's datasheet reads:

"The instruction is initiated by driving the /CS pin low and shifting the instruction code "90h" followed by a 24-bit address (A23-A0) of 000000h.  After which, the Manufacturer ID for Winbond (EFh) and the Device ID are shifted out on the falling edge of CLK with most significant bit (MSB) first as shown in Figure 39."

[image]

And my code is:
The response I get is always 255, 255 or 0, 0
main:

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();

    manualId = deviceId = 0;

    read_id = 0x90;
    zero1   = 0x00;
    zero2   = 0x00;
    zero3   = 0x00;

    //Enable SPI
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    //Send code
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &read_id, 1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero1,   1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero2,   1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero3,   1, 1000);

    //Recieve ID
    slaveToMaster = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &manualId, 1, 1000);
    slaveToMaster = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &deviceId, 1, 1000);    

    //Disable SPI
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

Full code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

//FLASH                                         CHIP
//--------------------------------
//  1-----------|------------PC 5
//  2-----------|------------PA 6 
//  3-----------|------------
//  4-----------|------------GND
//  5-----------|------------PA 7
//  6-----------|------------PA 5
//  7-----------|------------
//  8-----------|------------VCC
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);

#define spi_enable      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define spi_disable   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET)

HAL_StatusTypeDef masterToSlave, slaveToMaster;

uint8_t receive_data=0;
uint8_t read_id, zero1, zero2, zero3;
uint8_t manualId, deviceId;

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();

    manualId = deviceId = 0;

    read_id = 0x90;
    zero1   = 0x00;
    zero2   = 0x00;
    zero3   = 0x00;

    //Enable SPI
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    //Send code
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &read_id, 1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero1,   1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero2,   1, 1000);
    masterToSlave = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &zero3,   1, 1000);

    //Recieve ID
    slaveToMaster = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &manualId, 1, 1000);
    slaveToMaster = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &deviceId, 1, 1000);    

    //Disable SPI
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}


static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;//SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;//
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}



void Error_Handler(void)
{

  while(1) 
  {
  }
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
}

#endif
```

Comment: After `HAL_SPI_Transmit` you have to wait for the transmission to end like: `while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);`. Before transmitting or receiving again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have not started SPI Clock yet. Without starting SPI clock SPI won't get initialized and so communication won't take place.